# Normal vector to a regular star shaped region

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a star-shaped region (with respect to the origin $0$) with $C^1$ bundary.

Can you give a detailed proof of the following fact?

> if $x\in\partial U$ then for each $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|y-x|<\delta$ and $y\in\bar{U}$ imply 
>   $$\nu(x)\cdot\frac{y-x}{|y-x|}\le\varepsilon.$$

---

We say that $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ has $C^k$ boundary if, for all $x \in \partial \Omega$, there exists a neighborhood $O$ of $x$ and a map $T:Q \to O$ which is bijective, of class $C^k$ and with inverse of class $C^k$ and such that

$$T(Q_+) = O \cap \Omega$$
$$T(Q_0)= O \cap \partial \Omega,$$
where we have denoted 
$$Q=\{ (x',x_N) \in \mathbb{R}^{N-1}\times \mathbb{R}, |x'|< 1, |x_N|< 1\}$$
$$Q_+=\{ x \in Q: x_n >0\}$$
$$Q_0=\{ x \in Q: x_n =0\}$$

Comment: $\nu(x)$ is the normal unitary vector at $x$?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yes, it is.

Comment: The region $D_1(0,0)\cup (D_2(0,0)\cap \{y\ge 0\})$ can be approximated by a $C^1$ region and for points at the $X$-axis the statement is false.

Comment: @san: seems to me the only points at which it could be false are the sharp corners $(\pm1, 0)$, which would not be present in the smoothed version.

Comment: You are right @AnthonyCarapetis, I misunderstood the definition of $\nu(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the star-shaped assumption is unneccessary, since this is a purely local claim. To reduce confusion I'm going to rename your $x \in \partial \Omega$ to $p$, and WLOG assume that $T(0) = p$.

Since $\nu$ is the *outwards* normal vector, we must have $Z=\partial T/\partial x_N|_0 \cdot\nu < 0$, since travelling in the $+x_N$ direction moves in to the interior of $Q_+$.

Applying Taylor's theorem to $T$, we get $$T(x', x_N) = p + \frac{\partial T}{\partial x_N}\Big|_0 x_N + \frac{\partial T}{\partial x'}\Big|_0 \cdot x' + o(|x',x_N|)$$ and thus $$(T(x', x_N) -
 T(0) )\cdot \nu = Z x_N + o(|x',x_N|),$$ where the $x'$ term vanished because $\nu$ is orthogonal to $\partial T/\partial x'|_0$ by definition. Thus for any $\epsilon' > 0$ we can find a $\delta_1 > 0$ such that $$x_N \ge 0, |x',x_N| < \delta_1 \implies \left(\frac{T(x',x_N) - p}{|x',x_N|}\right)\cdot \nu<\epsilon'.$$ Since $T$ has invertible derivative at $0$, we can find $\delta_2>0$ such that $$|x',x_N| < \delta_2 \implies |x',x_N| < C |T(x',x_N) - p|$$ where $C$ is a fixed constant (anything larger than the operator norm of $|DT_0^{-1}|$ will do). Putting these together we find that $$x_N \ge 0, |x',x_N| <  \min(\delta_1, \delta_2) \implies \left(\frac{T(x',x_N) - p}{|T(x',x_N) - p|} \right) \cdot \nu < \frac {\epsilon'} C.$$

Since $T : Q_+ \cup Q_0 \to \bar \Omega \cap O$ is a bijection with continuous inverse, any $y \in \bar \Omega$ sufficiently close to $p$ can be written as $T(x',x_N)$ for some $(x',x_N)$ satisfying these assumptions, so choosing $\epsilon' = C \epsilon$ completes the proof.

Comment: I don't quite understand the last lines, would you mind elaborating a bit: "Since $T : Q_+ \cup Q_0 \to \bar \Omega \cap O$ is a bijection with continuous inverse, any $y \in \bar \Omega$ sufficiently close to $p$ can be written as $T(x',x_N)$ for some $(x',x_N)$ satisfying these assumptions, so choosing $\epsilon' = C \epsilon$ completes the proof."

Comment: Also, why don't we loose generality assuming $T(0)=p$? And what is a rigorous explanation to the fact that "$Z=\partial T/\partial x_N|_0 \cdot\nu < 0$, since travelling in the $+x_N$ direction moves in to the interior of $Q_+$"?

Comment: Finally, why "Since $T$ has invertible derivative at $0$, we can find $\delta_2>0$ such that $|x',x_N| < \delta_2 \implies |x',x_N| < C |T(x',x_N) - p|$"?

Comment: Thanks. I too would like to know the answers to the additional questions in the comments.

Comment: 1. The last lines are just using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity for $T^{-1}$ - there is some $\delta$ such that $|y-p| \le \delta \implies |T^{-1}(y)| < \min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$. 

2. If $T^{-1}(p) = q \ne 0$, by openness you can find a scaled-down version $Q'$ of $Q$ centred on $q$ that is contained in the original $Q$. Composing $T|_{Q'}$ with the scaling/translation map will give you a suitable $T' : Q' \to T'(O) \subset O$ with $T'(0) = p$. 3. To give a rigorous explanation I'd need your rigorous definition of $\nu$ - whatever it is, $Z<0$ should be very easy to prove.

Comment: 4. Letting $x=(x',x_N)$ and $y = T(x)$, we can write the desired inequality as $|T^{-1}(y) - T^{-1}(p)| < C|y - p|$. This is just Lipshitz continuity of $T^{-1}$, which holds on any ball $\Omega$ with constant $C = \sup_\Omega |DT^{-1}|.$ Since the derivative of $T^{-1}$ is also continuous, you can make $|DT^{-1}(y)|$ stay less than any $|DT^{-1}(p)|+\epsilon$ by keeping $y$ close enough to $p$, and by continuity of $T$ you can keep $y$ close to $p$ by keeping $x$ close enough (my $\delta_2$) to $0$.